# how I can get Validators.minLength of form input and set it in html dynamicly?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have a form in angular and I want to use value of form "Validators.minLength" in html input tag.

I want Know is any way to use directly from form validator in html;

sample:
[maxLength]="form.get('zipCode').validators('maxLength)"

My ts code is:

```
            zipCode: [ '', [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(10),
                number,
            ],
```

and html is:

```
                        <input type="tel"
                               formControlName="zipCode"
                               [maxLength]="10"  // here I want insert dynamic number from ts file
                               placeholder="insert your zip code">
```

tanks for your helping.

Answer (score 2):

TS

```
this.maxLength=10;
zipCode: [ '', [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(this.maxLength),
                number,
            ],
```

HTML

```
<input type="tel" formControlName="zipCode" placeholder="insert your zip code">
```

Comment: tanks for your answer, I want to know is a way to add maxlength value in input tag, sample: [maxLength]="form.get('zipCode').maxLength" ???

Comment: you can bind [maxLength] to a variable like this [maxLength] ="maxLength", but i didnt get the point, both are same right?

Comment: yes that's true but I have many fields same as this and it's not suitable way for me

Answer (score 1):

TS:

```
public maxZipCodeLength: number = 10;
```

HTML:

```
<input type="tel" formControlName="zipCode" [maxlength]="maxZipCodeLength" />
```

This should be enough.

Comment: tanks for your answer, I want Know is any way to use directly from form validator in html;
sample: [maxLength]="form.get('zipCode').validators('maxLength)"

Comment: That's bad way to do it. Keep in mind that according to official documentation if you use `maxlength` on html input, basically angular converts it to a form validator already. [https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#maxlength](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#maxlength). That means if you use `maxlength` on input, you don't have to use validator.